# Modify dereferenced struct pointer changes most struct values, but not slices

Tags: pointers, methods, go, slice, chess

I'm trying to create a shallow copy of a struct Board (a chessboard). Before saving a move to the board, I need to check if that move puts the mover in check.

To do so, within the Move method (method of a pointer), I **dereference** the pointer, update and check this ***possible*** board for Check. When I change the value of a single value of the Board type (such as `possible.headers = "Possible Varient"`) the original `b` Board is not changed.

But here when I call a method updateBoard() it updates both boards. I still receive the error (cannot move into check), but the main thread thinks `b.board` (the board position) has been changed.

```
func (b *Board) Move(orig, dest int) error {
    // validation
    ...
    // Update 
    possible := *b // A 'shallow copy'?
    possible.updateBoard(orig, dest, val, isEmpassant, isCastle)

    king := possible.findKingPositionOfThePlayerWhoMoved()
    isCheck := possible.isInCheck(king) // bool takes the king to check for

    if isCheck {
        return errors.New("Cannot move into Check")
    }
    b.updateBoard(orig, dest, val, empassant, isCastle)
    return nil
```

Strangely, not all the the values updated by `updateBoard()` change. So the `b.toMove` value doesn't change, but the `b.board` value does (the position of the pieces). This means if I pass `possible := b` instead, the game will only ever be white's move (toMove is alternated in the updateBoard() method). With `possible := *b`, turn alternation works until one moves into check. Then the move is applied to `b.board`, but the error is thrown back and it remains the checked-players turn (meaning `possible.updateBoard()` didn't update b.toMove.

**Edit**

As abhink pointed out, in [Go Slices usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals),

> Slicing does not copy the slice's data. It creates a new slice value that points to the original array.

`b.board`, a `[]byte`, always points to its original value (even when the struct which holds it is **dereferenced**. abhink's answer uses the Go `func copy(dst, src []Type) int`, https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy , a shortcut for copying the values of the pointers.

Comment: Is `b.board` a pointer type (`board` is a pointer to some board type)? If so, then a shallow copy `possible := *b` creates a new struct `possible` which has the same pointer address in its `board` field as `b.board`. Any access/modification now done through referencing `possible.board` will change the value for `b` too since both share the same pointer.

Comment: No, `b.board` is a `[]byte`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `b.board` is a slice type, it is a reference type (https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) and behaves like a pointer. So any changes made to `possible.board` will show up in `b`. You can try making a copy of `b.board` like so:

```
func (b *Board) Move(orig, dest int) error {
    // validation
    ...
    // Update 
    possible := *b // A 'shallow copy'?
    boardCopy := make([]byte, len(b.board))
    copy(boardCopy, b.board)
    possible.board = boardCopy

    possible.updateBoard(orig, dest, val, isEmpassant, isCastle)

    // ...
```

Note that you'll have to do something like this for all reference types.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing does NOT make a copy. It returns the original value your pointer points to.

You get a copy because you are assigning that value to a new variable. In go every assignment makes a copy as does every pass to a function. If you assign or pass a reference, that reference is copied.

In your case you copy the value b points to. In that struct there are pointers like the b.board slice (slices have a pointer to an underlying array). So go is creating a copy of the slice. The copy still points to the same array as the slice in the original b variable. If you change that array, it is changed for both your boards.

You will need to implement a copy function to your Board struct that correctly creates a copy of your struct handling each variable depending on its type and returns that new board.

Something like:

```
func (b *Board) copy() *Board {
  boardCopy := make([]byte, len(b.board))
  copy(boardCopy, b.board)

  return &Board{
    moveTo: b.moveTo,
    board: boardCopy
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope that helps and my explanation wasn't confusing :)