# Does dereferencing a struct return a new copy of struct?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, dereference

Why when we reference struct using `(*structObj)` does Go seem to return a new copy of `structObj` rather than return the same address of original `structObj`? This might be some misunderstanding of mine, so I seek clarification

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type me struct {
    color string
    total int
}

func study() *me {
    p := me{}
    p.color = "tomato"
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &p.color)
    return &p
}

func main() {
    p := study()
    fmt.Printf("&p.color = %p\n", &p.color)

    obj := *p
    fmt.Printf("&obj.color = %p\n", &obj.color)
    fmt.Printf("obj = %+v\n", obj)

    p.color = "purple"
    fmt.Printf("p.color = %p\n", &p.color)
    fmt.Printf("p = %+v\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("obj  = %+v\n", obj)

    obj2 := *p
    fmt.Printf("obj2 = %+v\n", obj2)
}
```

Output

```
0x10434120
&p.color = 0x10434120
&obj.color = 0x10434140   //different than &p.color!
obj = {color:tomato total:0}
p.color = 0x10434120
p = &{color:purple total:0}
obj  = {color:tomato total:0}
obj2 = {color:purple total:0} // we get purple now when dereference again
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HCvajBAnsb)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you write

```
obj := *p
```

You are copying the value of struct pointed to by `p` (`*` dereferences `p`). It is similar to:

```
var obj me = *p
```

So `obj` is a new variable of type `me`, being initialized to the value of `*p`. This causes `obj` to have a different memory address.

Note that `obj` if of type `me`, while `p` is of type `*me`. But they are separate values. Changing a value of a field of `obj` will not affect the value of that field in `p` (unless the `me` struct has a reference type in it as a field, i.e. slice, map or channels. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263511/go-modify-dereferenced-struct-pointer-changes-most-struct-values-but-not-slic/38263938#38263938) and [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).). If you want to bring about that effect, use:

```
obj := p
// equivalent to: var obj *me = p
```

Now `obj` points to the same object as `p`. They still have different addresses themselves, but hold within them the same address of the actual `me` object.

Comment: is there a way to get the same dereferenced pointer to p? as in the main() func, if we are appending the struct as a slice, we will always have to dereference it inside the append itself, i.e. res = append(res, *p).

Comment: It not just about "creating" a new variable, assignment to an existing variable via a dereference copies the value, e.g. `*a = *b` still copied copies `*b` to `*a`.

Comment: @jimB yap, is there a way to avoid the repeated copy? as basically the operation just need to deal with the same p struct.

Comment: @ken: I don't understand what you mean. You need some sort of value, so it's either going to be the struct value or a pointer value. If you want to reference the same struct or avoid copying you use a pointer.

Comment: @JimB okay, maybe i am thinking too much ;) I got what you mean, thanks for your replied!

Answer (score 19):

No, "assignment" always creates a copy in Go, including assignment to function and method arguments.  The statement `obj := *p` copies the value of `*p` to `obj`.

If you change the statement `p.color = "purple"` to `(*p).color = "purple"` you will get the same output, because dereferencing `p` itself does not create a copy.

Comment: in fact, coming from c background, this make me confuse. Thanks, think both answer are correct and reach me about the same time, so chose a more details, but upvote this for your answer too!

Comment: `dereferencing p itself does not create a copy` this clarified my confusion, thanks

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr** Dereferencing (using the `*` operator) in Go does not make a copy. It returns the value the pointer points to.

Comment: True, although an *assignment does copy*! (Note that for slices and maps it will only copy the header value, not the actual elements, so it may seem like it does not copy)